# Maven is adding a folder to a dependency URL and failing to download- jsonld-java - on move to windows

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, jitpack

I've been chasing a strange problem when moving `https://github.com/ehrbase/fhir-bridge/blob/develop/pom.xml` from a mac environment in VSCode to a Windows environment behind a firewall. After adding certs, Maven is able to download all dependencies, but for one, where an extra folder is being added to the URL:

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/jsonld-java/jsonld-java/jsonld-java/0.13.3/jsonld-java-0.13.3.bundle
```

The dependency exists at

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/jsonld-java/jsonld-java/0.13.3/jsonld-java-0.13.3.bundle
```

On the mac the correct URL is used.

Here's the config on Windows:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 17.0.2, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.2.8-hotspot
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

And on the Mac:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.1/libexec
Java version: 16.0.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Do you have a `settings.xml` configured?

Comment: nothing in settings.xml yet. The firewall is using zscaler and jsonld-java exists in the local cache as it does on the mac.

Comment: it seems your locally or mirror repository caches wrong lib, you can run `mvn clean install -U` to force maven check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories. If your mirror( private maven repository ) is cached wrong lib version or missing. You need to go to admin and then clear cache for specific lib you are working on

Comment: @Kolleyk The problem has been solved?

Comment: I solved this eventually, by excluding jsonld from spring-boot-starter-web in the pom.      

  
`
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.jsonld-java</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency> 
`

Comment: Same problem but on Ubuntu 20.04.4